# Regex {} parsing

Tags: regex, c#-4.0, regex-greedy

Hello I have a problem with parsing this text

```
{
    {
        {
            {[system1];1;1;0.612509325};
            {[system2];1;1;0.977659115};
            {[system3];1;1;36.97828732969};
            {[system4];1;1;61.43154423}
        };2.5469
    };
    {
        {
            {[system5];1;1;0.9613443};
            {[system6];1;1;2.06340392};
            {[system7];1;1;4.12680784};
            {[system8];1;1;6.18989626};
            {[system9];1;1;24.75958504758};
            {[system10];1;3;61.8989626189}
        };31.6952
    }
}
```

I need to parse it into an object like this

```
class Group
{
  Rate = 31.6952
  Systems = 
   {
    System5 = {[system5];1;1;0.9613443};
    System6 ={[system6];1;1;2.06340392};
    System7 ={[system7];1;1;4.12680784};
    System8 ={[system8];1;1;6.18989626};
    System9 ={[system9];1;1;24.75958504758};
    System10 ={[system10];1;3;61.8989626189}
   }
}
```

I tried

> ({[^{}]*})*

but it doesn't group it well.

Comment: Regular expression can't handle nested constructs.

Comment: Some flavors of regexes can handle nested constructs (Perl REs) but it is hard, and prone to errors... Better use a real parser / lexer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I think that statement may provoke some backlash from regex demigods :)

Comment: Please tag with the programming language you're using, as requested by the [regex] tag description.

Answer (score 1):

try this regex

```
{[\d\w]*.*?}
```

It will return

```
{[system5];1;1;0.9613443}
```

From

```
System5 = {[system5];1;1;0.9613443};
```

Comment: Add data, that you want to grab from string

Comment: I mean your regex is not working in the way it looks like it's intended to work. The whole match (excluding `{` and `}`) is actually performed by `.*`. The `[\d\w]*` will not match anything in this example.